# Direct downloading a xls file without writing it to the directory by Spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, export-to-excel, xls

I am using this [Spreadsheet](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/) gem to export xls file.

I have the following codes in my controller:

```
def export
  @data = Data.all

  book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
  sheet = book.create_worksheet :name => "data"

  contruct_body(sheet, @data)

  book.write "data.xls"
end
```

In this way, I can fill in the data and save it in the root directory.

But I want to download it instead of save it. How could I modify the code so that the user prompted to select his local directory to save the file? (better if without saving a copy in the server side)

Please help!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can send it to the browser without saving it as a local file at all as follows

```
spreadsheet = StringIO.new 
book.write spreadsheet 
send_data spreadsheet.string, :filename => "yourfile.xls", :type =>  "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

Comment: @RAJ create a new SO question and I'll take a look

Comment: Have encoding problem with solution.

Comment: This is not working anymore, it only opens a page with encoding problems :(

Answer (score 2):

You could try this code

```
book.write "data.xls"

send_file "/path/to/data.xls", :type => "application/vnd.ms-excel", :filename => "data.xls", :stream => false

# and then delete the file

File.delete("path/to/data.xls")
```

Passing `:stream => false` to `send_file` will instruct Rails to copy the entire file into memory before streaming, so using `File.delete` immediately after `send_file` would be fine since `send_file` returns immediately without waiting for the download to complete. Having said that, with very large files you may see some memory bottle necks depending on the  amount of  memory available.

HTH

Comment: Bravo! In fact I just found out this exact same way in the afternoon but waiting for further test. Your answer gave me confidence so I think I don't need to worry anymore ^^ Thanks!

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore (I just inherited an app that uses this solution...). If I remove the `File.delete` part, this works. I trieed to delete the file in an after filter, but it does not work either. As i understand it, 'stream: false' is no longer an option for this method, and the file will NOT be cached... Any insight ? or should i use send_data ?

Comment: additional info : the `stream` option allegedly disapeared between rails v 3.0.9 and 3.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is insanely old, but I was looking for it so someone else might be.

This is the answer. (I'm using Sinatra.)

https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/issues/125#issuecomment-370157753

Answer (score 0):

The case happen on mybody.
I used the ajax request by remote::true to export excel file, nothing display on browser without any error message on console. 
Delete the remote params from the form, it works well.