# How to show params in URL, but stay on this page when running AJAX search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters

I want to generate xls reports for AJAX search results. Is it possible to pass params for generating Excel document or add params in URL ?

Here is how I generating URL for downloading XLS document:

```
<%= link_to url_for(request.params.merge({:format => :xls}))  do%>
  <%= image_tag("excel.png")%> <b>Export</b>
 <% end %>
```

and it is working with standard search, but not with AJAX.

My js code for AJAX search

```
$('#run_report').submit(function () {  
  $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(),'script');  
  return false;  
});
```

Can someone suggest how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an xls dataType for ajax. The dataTypes I am aware of are xml, html, script, json, jsonp, text. So using ajax with an xls file may require a two step approach.

In my search to complete a task similar to your question I came across the following which may achieve the download you are looking for : [Downloading xls file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049939/direct-downloading-a-xls-file-without-writing-it-to-the-directory-by-spreadsheet) .Hopefully you will also find it useful.

Comment: I assume that you used something based on DanSingerman's suggestion? Ultimately I used PHPExcel which you may like to review.

Comment: I tried, but params not passing there... can I show you my code ?

Comment: Yes why don't you edit your question and add your findings to date.

Comment: I just get the same result. Params not passing there. I will post it later today, excuse me.